# Visual Studio 2008 Remote Debugging Error: "Unable to start program '*****.exe'"

Tags: remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to remote debug my .exe in VS2008, but when I try to start debug I am thrown an error:

> Unable to start program '*****.exe'. The application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Review the manifest file for possible errors.  Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. For more details, please see the application event log.

Can someone tell me what needs to be done in order to resolve this problem? Where the application event log is?

Answer (score 0):

Check out (and upvote, if it works) the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515450/installing-ms-debug-dlls-for-remote-debugging) for installing the redistributable for VS2008.

The Application Event Log can be seen thru Administrative Tools->Event Viewer in Control Panel, accessible from your Start menu.